# Finding which point is furthest from something using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, distance, proximity

Here is an example of what I am looking to do:

Which town in South Dakota is farthest from a Hospital?

Which tool would I use to be able to do this?

Comment: Hi Jessica, welcome to GIS.StackExchange. I assume with the arctoolbox tag you're using ArcGis. If you are using ArcGis 10 then you should be able to use either near or generate near table to determine what distances points are to other features (points, lines or polygons) and then you just have to find the biggest distance. Do you have multiple hospitals and need to find the furthermost for each?

Comment: I am using ArcGis 10.2. I am lookng at multiple hospitals to see which town is furthest and which hospital services how many towns.

Comment: I have also run the Near tool but I cannot figure out what the results mean. It adds distances to my hospital layer but it doesn't distance to what.

Comment: Use Near from the towns to the hospitals which will give you a distance to the closest hospital then you can sort the table by near fid (the id of the closest hospital) and by distance. If you have a lot of hospitals I recommend summary statistics to collapse to a single entry by distance then relate that to a town.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Use Near from the towns to the hospitals which will give you a
>   distance to the closest hospital then you can sort the table by near
>   fid (the id of the closest hospital) and by distance. If you have a
>   lot of hospitals I recommend summary statistics to collapse to a
>   single entry by distance then relate that to a town.